# how can i control servo motor through ros gui?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i have servo motor based robot and i want gui control for the robot in ros. so how can i control it??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/100051/how-can-i-control-servo-motor-through-ros-gui??/) by [pratikbhimani](https://answers.ros.org/users/8311/pratikbhimani/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-11-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[rqt_publisher](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_publisher) would be a good place to get started for publishing from a gui.  You're also going to need to make sure that you have the appropriate driver hooked up and configured for your servo motor's controller.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-11-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1